# text in top (status) bar

Tags: android, statusbar

Some apps (notably Lookout Mobile Security) show a text describing action done
for a short time (maybe 1 sec only) on the top (status) bar and then the display
goes back to the regular status bar (with a nice animation effect at least on HTC phones).
How is this done ?
I am not talking about notifications !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually part of the `Notification`. It is called the `tickerText`.
See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#tickerText

And, if developing on HoneyComb:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#tickerView

You can also pass the `tickerText` into the constructor of the `Notification`.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I tested in a program and it is ok. Only problem is that I do not want the final notification. I guess I will have to cancel it shortly after in a handler.

Comment: @E.Sarmas is that the solution you went for, I was thinking the same thing, did you find a better way?

Comment: In the past, I've done exactly that: post the notification and immediately cancel it. It worked well at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function [Activity.setTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) is what you're looking for.

Edit:

Or, you could produce a custom [notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) that only appears for one second.

Comment: I'd love to know how to make such a custom 1 second notification.